# Execute equation from the elements of a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following list and dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[5, 10, 40], [2, 15, 70], [6, 14, 60]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
lst = [5, '*', 'A', '+', 'C']
```

And I would like to create a code to execute the equation in the lst like `5 x A + C` returning the following result:

```
data = [[65], [80], [90]]
dresult = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['M'])
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You simply do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[5, 10, 40], [2, 15, 70], [6, 14, 60]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
lst = [5, '*', 'A', '+', 'C']

expression = ' '.join(str(e) for e in lst)

dresult = pd.DataFrame()
dresult['M'] = df.eval(expression)

print(dresult)
```

which is:

```
   M
0  65
1  80
2  90
```

**Edit**

In the multiindex case it would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[5, 10, 40], [2, 15, 70], [6, 14, 60]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'x'), ('B', 'x'), ('C', 'y')], names=['level_1', 'level_2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Value_3'])

lst = [5, '*', 'Value_1', '+', 'Value_3']
expression = ' '.join(str(e) for e in lst)

dresult = pd.DataFrame()
dresult['Result'] = df.eval(expression)

print(dresult)
```

which would give you

```
                 Result
level_1 level_2        
A       x            65
B       x            80
C       y            90
```

You cn then clean your df as you see fit.

Comment: You beat me ;) +1 (`df.eval(''.join(map(str, lst))).to_frame('M')`)

Comment: Can you use the eval if the column names are multiindex?

Comment: @Thanasis I added the multiindex case ;-)

Comment: Thank you @SergedeGossondeVarennes. But I was talking about multiindex in columns and not on the index. For example ```lst = [5, '*', '[A, Value_1]', '+', '[B, Value_3]']```